# light/dark mode in html, without CSS (only html)

Tags: html, css, darkmode

it there a way to make the HTML elements be in dark mode

if the user has activated in his system "dark mode" 
and if the user is like to use standard colors, to be "light mode"

all this automatically when the user opens the website.
without any buttons.

and I want that if the user changes the theme color preference from the setting, it will automatically switch to the correct one directly without refreshing the page.

the black and white color of text, I want that don't use any CSS

so not using CSS. in this project I am using only HTML.

```html
<!-- here is example of tags to color automatically for the answer -->
<h1>
<span>hello world<span>
<input>
```

if there a way to do this with one line or 2 maximum.

> maybe adding a library with no configuration needed, but I don't find it

Comment: But ... why no CSS? I don't think there's a single browser that (a) doesn't support CSS but  (b) lets pages specify light-mode vs dark-mode as such. (Pre-CSS graphical browsers might support the long-obsolete `bgcolor`, etc. attributes on the `body` element, but those do NOT affect any concept of color scheme, and the non-graphical browsers I've tried either let the *user* control whether to use a light background or a dark background, or don't support switching the background color in the first place.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

add this CSS property `color-scheme: light dark;` to the `<html>` css selector *(is only one line of css)*

OR if you need **only html** you can use this `<meta>` tag

```html
<meta 
  name    = "color-scheme" 
  content = "light dark"
/>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color-scheme

> watch [this](https://youtu.be/n3lcjY4Mm00) youtube video for more details: https://youtu.be/n3lcjY4Mm00

it does all the things you listed before!

[image]
[image]

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="color-scheme" content="light dark">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>hello world</h1>
  <span>hello world</span>
  <input type="text" placeholder="hello world">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Despite not answering the question, your approach would be even more helpful with a specific example (where to add the property in which exact way), please add a code example.

Comment: @LaaouatniAnas bro, worked with the meta tag, amazing! is really one line of code!!!!!! thank you

Comment: @IngoSteinke edited, added a code snippet below

Answer (score 1):

You can add meta tag in your  section if you want to use only HTML. You can use it like this:

```
    <head><meta name="color-scheme" content="light dark"></head>
<body>
  <h1>
<span>hello world<span>
<input>
</body>
```

Hope this helps you.