# How to change webview background color and text color in Swift

Tags: html, ios, swift, webview

I am loading dynamic html string which is coming from server response.
But, In my app, We are handling light and dark mode.
I am able to change webview's background color, but I am unable to change the text color.
It is showing always black text color irrespective of mode.

**I want to show black text color for light mode and white text color for dark mode.**

Any suggestions?

```
 func displayData() {
        
        if let contentData = self.response?.data?.content {
            do {
                self.webView.loadHTMLString(contentData, baseURL: nil)
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Edit the HTML with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72922557/light-dark-mode-in-html-without-css-only-html ?

Answer (score 0):

This has to be edited in the HTML webview that is being displayed.

CSS:

```
@media (prefers-color-scheme: light) { /* light mode */
    :root {
        --scheme-black-color: #000000;
        --scheme-white-color: #ffffff;
    }
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) { /* dark mode */
    :root {
        --scheme-black-color: #ffffff;
        --scheme-white-color: #000000;
    }
}

body {
    color: var(--scheme-black-color);
    background-color: var(--scheme-white-color);
}
```

In your .swift file you don't have to do anything else, it automatically changes the theme

Brendan