# How to use color-scheme with prefers-color-scheme together with a custom Theme-Switcher

Tags: javascript, html, css, themes

The CSS [`color-scheme` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color-scheme) was recently introduced *(at least to me)* and I have found some references *(listed below)* which mention how helpful it is. But none of them talk about what the best way to combine them together with a Theme-Switcher.

And by this I mean, I would like to build a website which has a custom Theme-Switcher button in it. So essentially,

- on first load, the website is going to apply the `color-scheme` based on the user's system default theme and then use `prefers-color-scheme` for further styles.
- But, once the user changes the theme using the Theme-Switcher, the preference is saved in browser local-storage and then used for future references.

---

So the question here is, once the user changes the website theme using the Theme-Switcher, whats the best way to switch the theme or color-scheme? Although this sounds straigtforward, I think its not. For Example:

1. If the system theme is dark and the user switches to light using Theme-Switcher, then the Canvas color-scheme would still be dark, but then website theme would be light and it would mis-match. Below Code-snippet shows an example.

Now, note that I do understand that I can set the text-color to switch based on the theme. But:

1. if I do that, then why would I need to use color-scheme in the first place?
2. more importantly, changing the style of form elements would especially be a challenge - which I hoped `color-scheme` would solve.

```js
let i = 1
let j = 1;

function ToggleTheme() {
  // console.log("Toggle Theme");
  i *= -1
  document.body.dataset.theme = i == 1 ? "light" : "dark"
}

function ToggleAllForm() {
  j *= -1;
  document.getElementById("allForm").style.display = j == 1 ? "none" : ""
}
```

```css
body[data-theme='light'] {
  background-color: black;
}

body[data-theme='dark'] {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta name="color-scheme" content="dark light">
</head>

<body data-theme="light">
  <button onclick="ToggleTheme()">Toggle Theme</button>
  <h1>Color-Scheme</h1>
  <form action="/action_page.php">
    <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="John"><br>
    <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="Doe"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>


  <hr>
  <br>
  <h1>All Form Elements</h1>
  <button onclick="ToggleAllForm()">Toggle All Form</button>
  <form id="allForm" style="display: none;">
    <div>
      <p>
        <label>
      text<br>
    <input type="text">
    </label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label>
      password<br>
    <input type="password">
    </label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label>
      number<br>
    <input type="number">
    </label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label>
      email<br>
    <input type="email">
    </label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label>
      url<br>
    <input type="url">
    </label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label>
      tel<br>
    <input type="tel">
    </label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label>
      search<br>
    <input type="search">
    </label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label>
      textarea<br>
      <textarea></textarea>
    </label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label>
      date<br>
    <input type="date">
    </label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label>
      datetime<br>
    <input type="datetime">
    </label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label>
      datetime-local<br>
    <input type="datetime-local">
    </label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label>
      month<br>
    <input type="month">
    </label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label>
      week<br>
    <input type="week">
    </label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label>
      time<br>
    <input type="time">
    </label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label>
      select<br>
      <select>
        <optgroup label="optgroup">
          <option>option 1</option>
          <option>option 2</option>
          <option>option 3</option>
        </optgroup>
      </select>
    </label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label>
      select (multiple attr)<br>
      <select multiple>
        <optgroup label="optgroup">
          <option>option 1</option>
          <option>option 2</option>
          <option>option 3</option>
        </optgroup>
      </select>
    </label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label>
      select (size attr)<br>
      <select size="4">
        <optgroup label="optgroup">
          <option>option 1</option>
          <option>option 2</option>
          <option>option 3</option>
        </optgroup>
      </select>
    </label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label>
      datalist<br>
      <input list="datalist">
      <datalist id="datalist">
        <option value="option 1">
        <option value="option 2">
        <option value="option 3">
      </datalist>
    </label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label>
      keygen<br>
      <keygen>
    </label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label>
      output<br>
      <output>123</output>
    </label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label>
      radio<br>
    <input type="radio">
    </label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label>
      checkbox<br>
    <input type="checkbox">
    </label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label>
      color<br>
    <input type="color">
    </label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label>
      range<br>
    <input type="range">
    </label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label>
      file<br>
    <input type="file">
    </label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label>
      submit<br>
    <input type="submit">
    </label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label>
      reset<br>
    <input type="reset">
    </label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label>
      button (input tag)<br>
    <input type="button" value="Button">
    </label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label>
      button (button tag)<br>
      <button>Button</button>
    </label>
      </p>
    </div>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>legend</legend>
      fieldset
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</body>
```

---

Reference:

1. [light/dark mode in html, without CSS (only html)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72922625/6908282)
2. [Light & Dark mode WITHOUT CSS! - Kevin Powell](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n3lcjY4Mm00)
3. [Improved dark mode default styling with the color-scheme CSS property and the corresponding meta tag](https://web.dev/color-scheme/)

Comment: The only way that I think would work is to switch the `color-scheme` as well in the `ToggleTheme` function using `document.querySelector('meta[name="color-scheme"]').setAttribute("content", theme);`